# Do I need a TaskService?

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to configure JBPM 5.4 persistence with spring +Hibernate4 + JPA2.

What I am doing is that I am creating a business approval process, say when user click Approve or Reject on UI, I just call session.getWorkItemManager.completeWorkItem to complete that human task and to continue the work flow. I only need to store the information that would enable he process to continue if the server crashed.

I guess I need SessionInfo, ProcessInstanceInfo and WorkItemInfo, so that I can retrieve Session with session id and do session.getWorkItemmanager.completeWorkItem a workitem using workItem id (I store workitem id on my side as well).

I think I am configuring Process Persistence, and I don't think I don't need TaskServer or TaskService. am I right? Please correct me if I am wrong.